# Cumulative sum that updates between two date ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have data that looks like this: (assume start and end are date times)

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01 | 01-02 |
| 1 | 01-03 | 01-05 |
| 1 | 01-04 | 01-07 |
| 1 | 01-06 | NaT |
| 1 | 01-07 | NaT |

I want to get a data frame that would include all dates, that has a 'cumulative sum' that only counts for the range they are in.

| dates | count |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01 | 1 |
| 01-02 | 0 |
| 01-03 | 1 |
| 01-04 | 2 |
| 01-05 | 1 |
| 01-06 | 2 |
| 01-07 | 3 |

One idea I thought of was simply using `cumcount` on the start dates, and doing a 'reverse cumcount' decreasing the counts using the end dates, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around doing this in pandas and I'm wondering whether there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Comment: you have a column id, is your plan to make the same operation groupby id?

Comment: @Ben.T Yes Indeed! I didn't add a different id in the question cause I thought I could do that part if it comes to it - the 'cumulative date range' was the tricky part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two options. first consider this data with only one id, note that your columns start and end must be datetime.

```
d = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     'start': [pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2021-01-03'),
               pd.Timestamp('2021-01-04'), pd.Timestamp('2021-01-06'),
               pd.Timestamp('2021-01-07')],
     'end': [pd.Timestamp('2021-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2021-01-05'),
             pd.Timestamp('2021-01-07'), pd.NaT, pd.NaT]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

so to get your result, you can do a `sub` between the `get_dummies` of start and end. then `sum` if several start and or end at the same dates, `cumsum` along the dates, `reindex` to get all the dates between the min and max dates available. create a function.

```
def dates_cc(df_):
    return (
        pd.get_dummies(df_['start'])
          .sub(pd.get_dummies(df_['end'], dtype=int), fill_value=0)
          .sum()
          .cumsum()
          .to_frame(name='count')
          .reindex(pd.date_range(df_['start'].min(), df_['end'].max()), method='ffill')
          .rename_axis('dates')
    )
```

Now you can apply this function to your dataframe

```
res = dates_cc(df).reset_index()
print(res)
#        dates  count
# 0 2021-01-01    1.0
# 1 2021-01-02    0.0
# 2 2021-01-03    1.0
# 3 2021-01-04    2.0
# 4 2021-01-05    1.0
# 5 2021-01-06    2.0
# 6 2021-01-07    2.0
```

Now if you have several id, like

```
df1 = df.assign(id=[1,1,2,2,2])
print(df1)
#    id      start        end
# 0   1 2021-01-01 2021-01-02
# 1   1 2021-01-03 2021-01-05
# 2   2 2021-01-04 2021-01-07
# 3   2 2021-01-06        NaT
# 4   2 2021-01-07        NaT
```

then you can use the above function like

```
res1 = df1.groupby('id').apply(dates_cc).reset_index()
print(res1)
#    id      dates  count
# 0   1 2021-01-01    1.0
# 1   1 2021-01-02    0.0
# 2   1 2021-01-03    1.0
# 3   1 2021-01-04    1.0
# 4   1 2021-01-05    0.0
# 5   2 2021-01-04    1.0
# 6   2 2021-01-05    1.0
# 7   2 2021-01-06    2.0
# 8   2 2021-01-07    2.0
```

that said, a more straightforward possibility is with `crosstab` that create a row per id, the rest is about the same manipulations.

```
res2 = (
    pd.crosstab(index=df1['id'], columns=df1['start'])
      .sub(pd.crosstab(index=df1['id'], columns=df1['end']), fill_value=0)
      .reindex(columns=pd.date_range(df1['start'].min(), df1['end'].max()), fill_value=0)
      .rename_axis(columns='dates')
      .cumsum(axis=1)
      .stack()
      .reset_index(name='count')
)
print(res2)
#     id      dates  count
# 0    1 2021-01-01    1.0
# 1    1 2021-01-02    0.0
# 2    1 2021-01-03    1.0
# 3    1 2021-01-04    1.0
# 4    1 2021-01-05    0.0
# 5    1 2021-01-06    0.0
# 6    1 2021-01-07    0.0
# 7    2 2021-01-01    0.0
# 8    2 2021-01-02    0.0
# 9    2 2021-01-03    0.0
# 10   2 2021-01-04    1.0
# 11   2 2021-01-05    1.0
# 12   2 2021-01-06    2.0
# 13   2 2021-01-07    2.0
```

the main difference between the two options is that this one create extra dates for each id, because for example 2021-01-01 is in id=1 but not id=2 and with this version, you get this date also for id=2 while in `groupby` it is not taken into account.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I'll have to read up on the methods you used like `crosstab` etc to fully understand it but it does solve my problem!

Comment: @Secret for the latest option, you can comment all the lines except the first one, and see the result, then uncomment the second line and see again the result etc, it is a good way to understand what's happening :)